# Counting rows where condition is met in at least one column

Tags: google-sheets

How can I write a formula that will count the number rows that meet a condition in one of the columns?

I found this to work in Excel:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(N2:DD14>2.5),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COLUMNS(N2:DD14)))^0)>0))
```

But how can I get something like this to work in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the same `mmult` approach in Google Sheets. Your problem may have been because of the lack of `arrayformula`.

```
=countif(arrayformula(mmult(N(A1:F9 > 10), transpose(iferror(A1:F1/0, 1)))), ">0")
```

Here A1:F9 is the array being processed, and ">10" is the condition. So, `N(A1:F9 > 10)` returns a 0-1 array of the same size. It is summed by rows using `mmult`. The second argument is a column of 1s; I use `iferror(A1:F1/0, 1)` to generate an array of 1s of the same size as A1:F1.

Finally, `countif` counts positive entries of the product, i.e., the rows with at least one positive number.